Trouble Replacing Scroll Event with IntersectionObserver
I’m working on a project where I want to highlight menu options when their corresponding sections reach the top of the viewport, with a 52px buffer. I initially implemented this using a scroll event listener, and it works well. Here’s the working code:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const topMargin = 52;
    const activeClasses = ['font-bold', 'text-black'];

    const categories = document.querySelectorAll('.category');
    const menus = document.querySelectorAll('.menus');

    menus.forEach(menu => {
        const menuNav = menu.querySelector('.menu-nav');
        const links = menuNav.querySelectorAll('.category-link');

        window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
            let currentCategory;

            categories.forEach((category, index) => {
                const rect = category.getBoundingClientRect();
                if (rect.top <= topMargin && rect.bottom > topMargin) {
                    currentCategory = category;
                }
            });

            if (currentCategory) {
                links.forEach(link => {
                    link.classList.remove(...activeClasses);
                    if (link.getAttribute('data-category') === currentCategory.id) {
                        link.classList.add(...activeClasses);

                        const navRect = menuNav.getBoundingClientRect();
                        const linkRect = link.getBoundingClientRect();

                        const scrollLeft = linkRect.left + menuNav.scrollLeft - navRect.left - (navRect.width / 2) + (linkRect.width / 2);

                        menuNav.scrollTo({
                            left: scrollLeft,
                            behavior: 'smooth'
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});

Since this solution works fine, I wanted to optimize it by replacing the scroll event listener with an IntersectionObserver. However, when I tried this approach, it didn’t work as expected. Here’s my attempt with the IntersectionObserver:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Configuration variables
    const topMargin = 52; // The top margin (in pixels) to trigger the active link
    const activeClasses = ['font-bold', 'text-black']; // Classes to add to the active link

    const categories = document.querySelectorAll('.category');
    const menus = document.querySelectorAll('.menus');

    menus.forEach(menu => {
        const menuNav = menu.querySelector('.menu-nav');
        const links = menuNav.querySelectorAll('.category-link');

        // Create an Intersection Observer
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                const link = Array.from(links).find(link => link.getAttribute('data-category') === entry.target.id);

                if (entry.isIntersecting && link) { // Ensure link is found
                    links.forEach(link => link.classList.remove(...activeClasses));
                    link.classList.add(...activeClasses);

                    // Smooth scroll for the active link in the menu-nav
                    const navRect = menuNav.getBoundingClientRect();
                    const linkRect = link.getBoundingClientRect();
                    
                    const scrollLeft = linkRect.left + menuNav.scrollLeft - navRect.left - (navRect.width / 2) + (linkRect.width / 2);
                    
                    menuNav.scrollTo({
                        left: scrollLeft,
                        behavior: 'smooth'
                    });
                }
            });
        }, {
            rootMargin: `-${topMargin}px 0px 0px 0px`, // Trigger when the category is within the topMargin
            threshold: 0 // Trigger as soon as the element enters the viewport
        });

        // Observe each category
        categories.forEach(category => observer.observe(category));
    });
});

When I switch to the IntersectionObserver implementation, the menu highlighting and smooth scrolling do not work as desired. The menu items do not highlight correctly and seems to count from the bottom.
How can I correctly replace the scroll event with an IntersectionObserver to achieve the same effect?


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            const topMargin = 52;
            const activeClasses = ['font-bold', 'text-black'];

            const categories = document.querySelectorAll('.category');
            const menus = document.querySelectorAll('.menus');

            menus.forEach(menu => {
                const menuNav = menu.querySelector('.menu-nav');
                const links = menuNav.querySelectorAll('.category-link');

                window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
                    let currentCategory;

                    categories.forEach((category, index) => {
                        const rect = category.getBoundingClientRect();
                        if (rect.top <= topMargin && rect.bottom > topMargin) {
                            currentCategory = category;
                        }
                    });

                    if (currentCategory) {
                        links.forEach(link => {
                            link.classList.remove(...activeClasses);
                            if (link.getAttribute('data-category') === currentCategory.id) {
                                link.classList.add(...activeClasses);

                                const navRect = menuNav.getBoundingClientRect();
                                const linkRect = link.getBoundingClientRect();

                                const scrollLeft = linkRect.left + menuNav.scrollLeft - navRect.left - (navRect.width / 2) + (linkRect.width / 2);

                                menuNav.scrollTo({
                                    left: scrollLeft,
                                    behavior: 'smooth'
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1 class="text-3xl font-extrabold">Desiered Effect</h1>
    <!-- Example Menu 1: Breakfast Menu -->
    <div class="menus flex flex-col border border-gray-200 rounded-lg w-full p-3 mb-6">

        <!-- Menu title and description -->
        <div class="flex flex-col mb-4">
            <div class="font-bold text-xl">Breakfast Menu</div> <!-- Menu Name -->
            <div class="text-gray-600">Start your day right with our delicious breakfast options.</div> <!-- Menu Description -->

            <!-- Availability -->
            <div class="text-sm font-medium mt-2">
                <span>Monday - Friday: 6:00 AM - 11:00 AM</span>
            </div>
            <div class="text-sm font-medium">
                <span>Saturday - Sunday: 7:00 AM - 12:00 PM</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Menu categories navigation -->
        <div class="menu-nav flex flex-row gap-x-4 overflow-x-scroll text-gray-600 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium py-4 sticky top-0 bg-white">
            <a class="category-link cursor-pointer" href="#pancakes" data-category="pancakes">Pancakes</a>
            <a class="category-link cursor-pointer" href="#omelettes" data-category="omelettes">Omelettes</a>
            <a class="category-link cursor-pointer" href="#smoothies" data-category="smoothies">Smoothies</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Categories and items -->
        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-3">
            <!-- Category 1: Pancakes -->
            <div id="pancakes" class="category flex flex-col gap-y-3 border border-red-200 p-3">
                <div class="text-2xl font-bold">Pancakes</div> <!-- Category Title -->

                <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-y-3 gap-x-3 md:basis-1/2 flex-nowrap">
                    <!-- Menu item 1 -->
                    <div class="flex flex-row border-b last:border-0 md:last:border md:border md:rounded-lg border-gray-200 pb-3 w-full md:p-3">
                        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-1">
                            <div class="text-lg font-bold">Classic Pancakes</div> <!-- Item Name -->
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-600 pr-6">Fluffy pancakes served with maple syrup and butter.</div> <!-- Item Description -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Menu item 2 -->
                    <div class="flex flex-row border-b last:border-0 md:last:border md:border md:rounded-lg border-gray-200 pb-3 w-full md:p-3">
                        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-1">
                            <div class="text-lg font-bold">Blueberry Pancakes</div> <!-- Item Name -->
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-600 pr-6">Pancakes filled with fresh blueberries and served with a blueberry compote.</div> <!-- Item Description -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Category 2: Omelettes -->
            <div id="omelettes" class="category flex flex-col gap-y-3 border border-red-200 p-3">
                <div class="text-2xl font-bold">Omelettes</div> <!-- Category Title -->

                <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-y-3 gap-x-3 md:basis-1/2 flex-nowrap">
                    <!-- Menu item 1 -->
                    <div class="flex flex-row border-b last:border-0 md:last:border md:border md:rounded-lg border-gray-200 pb-3 w-full md:p-3">
                        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-1">
                            <div class="text-lg font-bold">Cheese Omelette</div> <!-- Item Name -->
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-600 pr-6">A fluffy omelette filled with cheddar, mozzarella, and parmesan cheese.</div> <!-- Item Description -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Menu item 2 -->
                    <div class="flex flex-row border-b last:border-0 md:last:border md:border md:rounded-lg border-gray-200 pb-3 w-full md:p-3">
                        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-1">
                            <div class="text-lg font-bold">Veggie Omelette</div> <!-- Item Name -->
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-600 pr-6">Omelette packed with spinach, mushrooms, bell peppers, and onions.</div> <!-- Item Description -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Category 3: Smoothies -->
            <div id="smoothies" class="category flex flex-col gap-y-3 border border-red-200 p-3">
                <div class="text-2xl font-bold">Smoothies</div> <!-- Category Title -->

                <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-y-3 gap-x-3 md:basis-1/2 flex-nowrap">
                    <!-- Menu item 1 -->
                    <div class="flex flex-row border-b last:border-0 md:last:border md:border md:rounded-lg border-gray-200 pb-3 w-full md:p-3">
                        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-1">
                            <div class="text-lg font-bold">Berry Blast Smoothie</div> <!-- Item Name -->
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-600 pr-6">A refreshing blend of strawberries, blueberries, and raspberries.</div> <!-- Item Description -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Menu item 2 -->
                    <div class="flex flex-row border-b last:border-0 md:last:border md:border md:rounded-lg border-gray-200 pb-3 w-full md:p-3">
                        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-1">
                            <div class="text-lg font-bold">Mango Tango Smoothie</div> <!-- Item Name -->
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-600 pr-6">Tropical smoothie with mango, pineapple, and a hint of lime.</div> <!-- Item Description -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Example Menu 2: Lunch Menu -->
    <div class="menus flex flex-col border border-gray-200 rounded-lg w-full p-3 mb-6">

        <!-- Menu title and description -->
        <div class="flex flex-col mb-4">
            <div class="font-bold text-xl">Lunch Menu</div> <!-- Menu Name -->
            <div class="text-gray-600">Our lunch menu features a variety of hearty meals and light bites.</div> <!-- Menu Description -->

            <!-- Availability -->
            <div class="text-sm font-medium mt-2">
                <span>Monday - Friday: 11:30 AM - 2:30 PM</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Menu categories navigation -->
        <div class="menu-nav flex flex-row gap-x-4 overflow-x-scroll text-gray-600 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium py-4 sticky top-0 bg-white">
            <a class="category-link cursor-pointer" href="#sandwiches" data-category="sandwiches">Sandwiches</a>
            <a class="category-link cursor-pointer" href="#salads" data-category="salads">Salads</a>
            <a class="category-link cursor-pointer" href="#soups" data-category="soups">Soups</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Categories and items -->
        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-3">
            <!-- Category 1: Sandwiches -->
            <div id="sandwiches" class="category flex flex-col gap-y-3 border border-red-200 p-3">
                <div class="text-2xl font-bold">Sandwiches</div> <!-- Category Title -->

                <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-y-3 gap-x-3 md:basis-1/2 flex-nowrap">
                    <!-- Menu item 1 -->
                    <div class="flex flex-row border-b last:border-0 md:last:border md:border md:rounded-lg border-gray-200 pb-3 w-full md:p-3">
                        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-1">
                            <div class="text-lg font-bold">Turkey Club</div> <!-- Item Name -->
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-600 pr-6">Sliced turkey, bacon, lettuce, tomato, and mayo on toasted bread.</div> <!-- Item Description -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Menu item 2 -->
                    <div class="flex flex-row border-b last:border-0 md:last:border md:border md:rounded-lg border-gray-200 pb-3 w-full md:p-3">
                        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-1">
                            <div class="text-lg font-bold">Grilled Cheese</div> <!-- Item Name -->
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-600 pr-6">A classic grilled cheese with cheddar on sourdough bread.</div> <!-- Item Description -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Category 2: Salads -->
            <div id="salads" class="category flex flex-col gap-y-3 border border-red-200 p-3">
                <div class="text-2xl font-bold">Salads</div> <!-- Category Title -->

                <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-y-3 gap-x-3 md:basis-1/2 flex-nowrap">
                    <!-- Menu item 1 -->
                    <div class="flex flex-row border-b last:border-0 md:last:border md:border md:rounded-lg border-gray-200 pb-3 w-full md:p-3">
                        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-1">
                            <div class="text-lg font-bold">Caesar Salad</div> <!-- Item Name -->
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-600 pr-6">Crisp romaine lettuce, croutons, parmesan, and Caesar dressing.</div> <!-- Item Description -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Menu item 2 -->
                    <div class="flex flex-row border-b last:border-0 md:last:border md:border md:rounded-lg border-gray-200 pb-3 w-full md:p-3">
                        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-1">
                            <div class="text-lg font-bold">Greek Salad</div> <!-- Item Name -->
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-600 pr-6">Mixed greens, cucumbers, tomatoes, olives, feta, and Greek dressing.</div> <!-- Item Description -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Category 3: Soups -->
            <div id="soups" class="category flex flex-col gap-y-3 border border-red-200 p-3">
                <div class="text-2xl font-bold">Soups</div> <!-- Category Title -->

                <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-y-3 gap-x-3 md:basis-1/2 flex-nowrap">
                    <!-- Menu item 1 -->
                    <div class="flex flex-row border-b last:border-0 md:last:border md:border md:rounded-lg border-gray-200 pb-3 w-full md:p-3">
                        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-1">
                            <div class="text-lg font-bold">Tomato Soup</div> <!-- Item Name -->
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-600 pr-6">Rich and creamy tomato soup served with a slice of garlic bread.</div> <!-- Item Description -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Menu item 2 -->
                    <div class="flex flex-row border-b last:border-0 md:last:border md:border md:rounded-lg border-gray-200 pb-3 w-full md:p-3">
                        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-1">
                            <div class="text-lg font-bold">Chicken Noodle Soup</div> <!-- Item Name -->
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-600 pr-6">Hearty chicken soup with egg noodles, carrots, and celery.</div> <!-- Item Description -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



